# I'm trying to find the highest number in a text file on my desktop using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, iteration

I'm trying to write a bit of code that looks through a text file on my desktop and spits out the highest number from that file into a new file on my desktop.

I'm not sure if the error is with the file extension or some other part of the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Lab1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("/Users/tylerprosper/Desktop/numberlist.rtf"));
            int largest = file.nextInt();

            while(file.hasNextInt()) {
                int number = file.nextInt();

                if(number > largest) {
                    largest = number;
                }

                System.out.println(number);
            }

            file.close();

            System.out.println("The biggest number in the file is: " + largest);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:860)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2161)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2115)
    at Lab1.main(Lab1.java:9)
```

The contents of the text file are numbers 1-9 each on their own line, consecutively, like such:

`1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9`

Here is a link to a screencap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sajZc.jpg

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Obviously, you are trying to read an RTF file as a plaintext file and this causes an error when trying to get `file.nextInt()`

Comment: The exact error is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:860)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1497)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2161)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2115)
 at Lab1.main(Lab1.java:9)`

Comment: Let's see an example of what is in file (copy & paste it in an edit session for your current post here).

Comment: It's a text file that has numbers 1-9 each on their own line, consecutively, like such:

`
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
`

Here is a link to a screencap: https://imgur.com/gP3AgjE

Comment: I see...try this: `int largest = 0;`

Comment: Remove the first line of your text file, it looks like it's a blank line, which is not an int, this looks more like a typo in your text file input than an issue with scanners

Comment: If your text file is indeed a **Plain ASCII Text** file and not a **.rtf** (Rich Text Format) file and you know it contains pure integer values then you really shouldn't have any problem with your code even with blank lines, white-spaces, or tabs before or after your digits. Work done between the **Scanner.hasNextInt()** and **Scanner.nextInt()** methods should clean it up for you. Take a look at your file within an ASCII Text Editor, if the file is RTF you will see all sorts of RTF formating tags etc. In your Editor, save the file as Plain Ascii Text.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to store your data in .rtf format, you can try the code below. It use RTFEditorKit to read in .rtf file as a document object, then iterate through the document to get the data and do the comparison accordingly. Anyway i wont suggest you to use .rtf, use a plain text file instead so you can skip this tedious step. You can simply use the code you have writen to reach your goal if you are using a plain text file.

```
File inputFile = new File("/Users/tylerprosper/Desktop/numberlist.rtf");
RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
Document document = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();
rtfParser.read(new FileInputStream(inputFile), document, 0);

int size = document.getLength();
 int largest = 0;
int number ;

// i+=2 is to skip the next line character
for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i+=2)
{
    String text = document.getText(i,1);
    number = Integer.parseInt(text);

     if(number > largest) {
         largest = number;
     }

      System.out.println(number);
}

System.out.println("The biggest number in the file is: " + largest);
```